# ListView ItemClick event not firing for custom ListView adapter

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android, android-listadapter

So my ItemClick event in my Main Activity isn't firing when I click on items from my Custom ListView. I've looked at other answers and thought that the two Image buttons would be taking the focus away, so I have tried different ways to set focusability to false for both buttons and even tried it on the ImageView but so far it doesn't work. Could someone tell me why? Here is my code.

The Markup for Each Item.

**Layout1.axml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFDAFF7F"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/SpiceRowItem">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#000000"
         />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Text"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip">
            <TextView
                android:text="Allspice"
                android:id="@+id/Heading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF7F3300"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="italic"
         />
            <TextView
                android:text="Warm, sweet"
                android:id="@+id/Flavour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                android:textColor="#FF267F00"
         />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ImageWrap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <ImageButton
            android:text="Cupboard"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:id="@+id/AddToCupboard" />
        <ImageButton
            android:text="List"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:id="@+id/AddToList" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And the GetView method from my custom adapter (I'm using delegates so I can encapsulate the variable "position"):

**SpiceListAdapter.cs**

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null)
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, null, false);
            }

            ImageView Thumbnail = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Thumbnail);
            TextView Heading = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Heading);
            TextView Flavour = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Flavour);
            ImageButton AddToCupboard = row.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.AddToCupboard);
            ImageButton AddToList = row.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.AddToList);
            RelativeLayout SpiceRowItem = row.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.SpiceRowItem);

            //Populates heading and flavour of each row

            Heading.Text = mItems[position].name.ToString();
            Flavour.Text = mItems[position].flavour.ToString();

            //Populate button pictures

            if (mItems[position].cupboard)
            {
                AddToCupboard.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.CupboardClosed);
            }
            else
            {
                AddToCupboard.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.CupboardOpen);
            }
            if (!mItems[position].list)
            {
                AddToList.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ListEmpty);
            }
            else
            {
                AddToList.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ListFull);
            }

            //Adds Thumbnail picture

            var id = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(mItems[position].picture.ToString()).GetValue(null);
            Thumbnail.SetImageResource(id);

            //Adds onclick event for "Add to cupboard"

            AddToCupboard.Click += delegate
            {
                string RemMessage = "Removed From Cupboard";
                string AddMessage = "Added To Cupboard";
                mItems[position].cupboard = !mItems[position].cupboard;
                if (!mItems[position].cupboard)
                {
                    AddToCupboard.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.CupboardOpen);
                    Toast.MakeText(mContext, RemMessage, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    AddToCupboard.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.CupboardClosed);
                    Toast.MakeText(mContext, AddMessage, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }

            };

            //Adds onclick event for "Add to shopping list"


            AddToList.Click += delegate
            {
                string RemMessage = "Removed From Shopping List";
                string AddMessage = "Added To Shopping List";
                mItems[position].list = !mItems[position].list;
                if (!mItems[position].list)
                {
                    AddToList.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ListEmpty);
                    Toast.MakeText(mContext, RemMessage, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    AddToList.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ListFull);
                    Toast.MakeText(mContext, AddMessage, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            };
                return row;
          }
```

And finally it's implementation in Main Activity:

**MainActivity.cs**

```
//Instantiate Adapters
            SpiceListAdapter _adapter = new SpiceListAdapter(this, spices);
            SpiceListAdapter _CupboardAdapter = new SpiceListAdapter(this, cupboard);
            SpiceListAdapter _ShoppingAdapter = new SpiceListAdapter(this, shoppingList);
            _lv.Adapter = _adapter;

//Click Event handlers
            _lv.ItemClick += _lv_ItemClick;

private void _lv_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Poop");
        }
```

p.s. for some reason I use silly console strings when testing things out, it just keeps me sane :D.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the property in code like this:

//for  AddToCupboard

```
AddToCupboard.Focusable = false;
AddToCupboard.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
AddToCupboard.Clickable = true;
AddToCupboard.Click += delegate
        {
           //....
        };
```

// for  AddToList

```
AddToList.Focusable = false;
AddToList.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
AddToList.Clickable = true;
AddToList.Click += delegate
        {
           //....
        };
```

Another method:
 the easiest way doing it is setting its root ViewGroup to `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`, so it will block every control of it getting focused.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFDAFF7F"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:id="@+id/SpiceRowItem">
```

Comment: I had tried it all but it never worked :-| but I did find a workaround. Ill post the code soon.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per se but it is a workaround that solved my problem that might be useful to other people.

So I created a class that held a single int variable and instantiated it in MainActivity (could of just declared an int but I fancied having a class to hold data since objects pass by reference)

```
 class PosHolder
    {
        public int pos { get; set; }
    }
```

And in MainActivity

```
PosHolder _pos = new PosHolder();
```

I passed both my chosen function as lambda expression and _pos into my adapter constructor

```
SpiceListAdapter _adapter = new SpiceListAdapter(this, spices, () => { MyFunction(); }, _pos);
```

In my adapter class I create an Action, added a click listener to my root axml layout node. This click event changes the value of _pos to "position" then uses the click.Invoke() method to call the function passed into the constructor.

```
//create action
public Action Click { get; set; }
// Adapter Constructor
public SpiceListAdapter(Context context, List<Spice> names, Action click, PosHolder Pos)
        {
            mItems = names;
            mContext = context;
            Click = click;
            mPos = Pos;
            mCupboard = cupboard;
            mShopList = shoppingList;
        }
//Click event
SpiceRowItem.Click += delegate
            {
                mPos.pos = position;
                Click?.Invoke();
            };
```

I'ts probably far from best practice but it works for me and sorted my issue out.

Hope it helps.